# Repositioning UIButtons in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, rotation

Noob here. Various similar questions on SO but still can't figure it out.  I have a pair of buttons on the main view and a pair of buttons in a scroll view (embedded in the main view). Each pair of buttons are positioned on opposite ends of the display.  The scroll view covers the bottom half of the display.

When I rotate from portrait to landscape the pair of buttons in the main view are properly repositioned on opposite ends of the display based on their layout constraints.  But the buttons in the scroll view are not properly repositioned.  The scroll view itself properly expands in landscape mode (as seen by the background color) but the buttons do not move.  Both sets of buttons have the same layout constraints.  How can I make the buttons in the scroll view mimic the buttons in the main view?  In other words, how can I move the pair of buttons in the scroll view to opposite ends in landscape mode?

I don't have any custom code, everything was done with interface builder.  I'm using iOS 6.1 and xcode 4.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The autolayout tends to be a bit confusing.  You can custom position the elements once the screen has rotated. These are the methods that iOS will call when the device is rotated.  Just give the buttons outlets and adjust them inside of those methods

If before rotation, override from UIViewController:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
 // do something before rotation
}
```

If you want to perform something after rotation:

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
 // do something after rotation
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!  I was hoping for a code-free solution.  Is the autolayout feature that deficient in scroll view?  Does this mean that layout constraints are irrelevant (i.e., ignored/deprioritized) in scroll views??

Comment: the scrollview is a container for other views, so even though it will rotate, it will not automatically rotate the things inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem without requiring any hand code.  I added a single content view to the scroll view and then added my subviews (i.e., UIButtons) to the content view.

I fixed the height of the content view by adding a height constraint, anchored the left, top, and right sides of the content view to the scroll view (did not anchor the bottom to keep the content view from shrinking in landscape mode).  Also, anchored the scroll view (left, top, right, and bottom) to its superview to make sure it properly shrank in height and expanded in width in landscape mode.

The secret to success was in the layout constraints.  Once I fully -- and I mean fully -- understood the constraints, it all became crystal clear.